# Using `&mut self` in an async move block

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I have a `WriterJob` struct. Its functionality is not important; what it does is that it spawns a long-running task and provides callers an api to check the status of the job.

```
pub(crate) struct WriterJob {
    ...,
    status: Status,
}

impl WriterJob {
    async fn writer_job_impl(&mut self, rx: Receiver<WriteCommand>) {
       // Job implementation details. It's important that `self` is mutuable
       // since I update the job status
       // eg.
       // self.status = Status::Ready;
    }

    pub(crate) fn status(&self) -> Status {
       self.status
    }

    pub(crate) fn spawn_writer_job(&mut self) -> Sender<WriteCommand> {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(10);

        let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
            self.writer_job_impl(rx).await;
        });

        self.status = Status::Spawned;

        tx
    }
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
  --> src/io/buffered_write.rs:92:22
   |
89 |       pub(crate) fn spawn_writer_job(&mut self) -> Sender<WriteCommand> {
   |                                      ---------
   |                                      |
   |                                      `self` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
   |                                      let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
92 |           let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
   |  ______________________^
93 | |             self.writer_job_impl(rx).await;
94 | |         });
   | |          ^
   | |          |
   | |__________`self` escapes the associated function body here
   |            argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

I think I understand that the compiler is complaining that it doesn't know whether `self` will live as long as the spawned task hence a lifetime error. But I'm not sure what a good approach to this is. One possibility is to use `Arc<Mutex<Status>>` or `Arc<RwLock<Status>>` but I don't like this approach because I will probably need to add more mutuable fields in `self`. Are there cleaner ways to do this?

Comment: Also consider, how does the compiler enforce that you don't borrow `self` again while the spawned task is running? It doesn't know how long the task will run for so the only way to make that work is by _moving_ `self` or by using interior mutability.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might also be able to use [scoped tasks](https://docs.rs/tokio-scoped/latest/tokio_scoped/).

Comment: Using `pub(crate)` on a `struct` that is already set that way seems a bit redundant.

Comment: Extract `status` to a separate state struct, and wrap it with `Arc<Mutex>`. You want to read and write it from different threads, so you've got to sync it somehow. If you don't want to have a mutex, switch to atomics or atomic enums.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assume that the `self` isn't dropped during execution of the `handle` that's the why it throws the error. Instead, you can change the design of your structure to make it work

1. Create a sub struct with data you need to share between threads

```
struct WriteJobInner {
    ...,
    status: Status,
}
```

2. Create the struct to execute operations on shader data

```
// you can use 'std::sync::Mutex' if you need to touch the data in non-async
// functions
use tokio::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::Arc;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub(crate) struct Writejob {
    inner: Arc<Mutex<WriteJobInner>>,
}
```

Also, probably you can replace the tokio's mutex with `tokio::sync::RwLock` which is much better if many threads try to perform immutable operation on the data which lets to many threads read the data without blocking other read-only threads.

3. The final step is to implement `WriteJob` functions and you can use `&self` instead of `&mut self` because you modify data with protected with mutex.

```
impl WriterJob {
    async fn writer_job_impl(&self, rx: Receiver<WriteCommand>) {
       // Job implementation details. It's important that `self` is mutuable
       // since I update the job status
       // eg.
       // *self.inner.lock().await.status = Status::Ready;
    }

    pub(crate) async fn status(&self) -> Status {
       // make sure the `status` implements copy trait
       *self.inner.lock().await.status
    }

    pub(crate) fn spawn_writer_job(&self) -> Sender<WriteCommand> {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(10);
        // creates a new instance `Self` but all the instances of `self.inner`
        // references to the same shared state because it's wrapped by the
        // shader pointer `Arc`
        let writer = self.clone();

        let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
            writer.writer_job_impl(rx).await;
        });

        *self.inner.status.lock().await = Status::Spawned;

        tx
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to the problem is to use interior mutability. By changing the `Status` field to a `Cell<Status>` - or an atomic type, crossbeam's `crossbeam::atomic::AtomicCell` comes to mind - you can remove the `mut` and lifetime restrictions.

Let's say you move your `status` field into an inner type; I called it `WriterJobInner`. The `WriterJob` now only owns an `Arc<WriterJobInner>`:

```rust
pub(crate) struct WriterJob {
    inner: std::sync::Arc<WriterJobInner>,
}

struct WriterJobInner {
    pub status: std::cell::Cell<Status>,
}

struct WriteCommand;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Status {
    None,
    Spawned,
    Ready,
}
```

If you want, you can implement `Deref` for `WriterJob` to simplify some of the accesses.

Your `WriterJob` implementation would now change to this:

```rust
impl WriterJob {
    pub(crate) fn spawn_writer_job(&self) -> tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender<WriteCommand> {
        let (tx, rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(10);

        // Clone the Arc and move it to the background thread.
        let inner = self.inner.clone();
        let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
            inner.writer_job_impl(rx).await;
        });

        // TODO: Set only to Spawned if still None
        self.inner.status.set(Status::Spawned);
        tx
    }

    pub(crate) fn status(&self) -> Status {
        self.inner.status()
    }
}
```

Since the thread doesn't need to pass `self` - neither mutably nor immutably - the error goes away. In addition, since `status` is now a `Cell`, it also does not require `mut self`.

Likewise, your `WriterJobInner` also only takes `&self`:

```rust
impl WriterJobInner {
    pub async fn writer_job_impl(&self, rx: tokio::sync::mpsc::Receiver<WriteCommand>) {
        // ...
        self.status.set(Status::Ready);
    }

    pub fn status(&self) -> Status {
        self.status.get()
    }
}

unsafe impl Send for WriterJobInner {}
unsafe impl Sync for WriterJobInner {}
```

On a downside, the `WriterJobInner` type is required to be both `Send` and `Sync` in order to be used with `Arc<T>`, but you're using it cross-thread anyway.

Note that setting the `status` to `Spawned` after the thread was created is a race condition. You way want to try to atomically set the value only if it wasn't already set to something else.

---

In this approach, the most useful mix is likely one where you bundle everything together that needs to be changed together and then use exterior mutability for it.

Using `RwLock` (or similar) above here, e.g. as `inner: Arc<RwLock<..>>`, requires that you either mix sync with async code (`std::sync::RwLock` in an `async` method) or make your accessors `async` (when using `tokio::sync::RwLock`).